# Import data in mysql is getting lost

Tags: mysql, liquibase

Imported data in MySQL seems to get lost after logging out from it.
These are the steps I've done:

1. created a database and use the new database
2. . daily_data.sql
3. show tables and data if import was successful
4. I logout and login again, the database is already empty

If I remember correctly, I ran a query 2 days ago because I was having another problem of running a liquibase migrate

```
UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK 
SET LOCKED=FALSE,LOCKGRANTED=null,LOCKEDBY=null where ID=1;
```

Comment: Are you able to post daily_data.sql (without any sensitive data)?

Comment: Sorry for the question. I think this is not a problem as I first thought.

I thought that when running the 'use database_name' and run the '\. script.sql' 
It would import the data on that database
But it seems to import the data to the database name specified inside the script.

Thanks for the reply adamdc78